# Using DropDownListFor with model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

On my view I am using a list as my model and each list item is of type model, so it looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model>
```

and I am trying to loop through this list and add a specific property to a DropDownListFor:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ElementAt(i).module, new SelectList(Model, Model.ElementAt(i).module));
}
```

But when I do this it doesn't render a dropdownmenu on my page.

[image: Image of my list in locals]

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't render a dropdown list for a model because there is no way of representing the model in its entirety in a dropdown. What is ASP.NET supposed to render?

What you can do if you would like to select a model from a list is to run a LINQ `Select` query on the list, whereby you create an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` like this:

```
var selectList = Model
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Name = x.module_name,
        Value = x.module
    });
```

I have tried to take the values from the screenshot that you posted. Apologies if I made an error. You get the idea...

What this code does is loop through the collection of your object type (`Model.Select`) and returns a collection of `SelectListItem`. If you are unfamiliar with LINQ you need to think of `Select` as a transformative function. It takes a collection, and for each element transforms it into something else and returns the result. Here, it takes each element of the Model collection and creates a `SelectListItem`. It then returns an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

To render the list on the page you do the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model.MyValue, selectList)
```

...where Model.MyValue is the variable which receives the selected value (assuming that the value, `model` is a `string`, which it appears to be).

Comment: I can't get your code to work. selectList does not exist in current context. Am I missing something?

Comment: `selectList` is the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` that I defined in the first code block! You need to do that bit first.

Comment: I feel confused because I am new to using LINQ. If on my view my model is a list collection with each item in that collection an object and each object has module property with a value. How do I loop through this collection and take the module value?

Comment: A `Select` expression does the looping for you (which is what I did). To loop through a collection and take the module value you do collection.Select(x => x.module) which will return an `IEnumerable<type of the module property>`. This is exactly what I am doing in my answer, except that I am merging a couple steps and doing what you want to do more concisely.

Comment: Thanks I now understand how it works. I ended up using this code: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().module, Model.Select(x => new SelectListItem{Text = x.module, Value = x.module}))